# javafx 8 overlapping layers eventhandling

Tags: javafx, event-handling, javafx-8

I have two layers in my program with different elements in each layer. The two layers are overlapping but the elements in the layers are not. I want to show a tooltip when the mouse hovers over a node in each layer but right now the top layer only gets the event.

Below is attached a minimal example:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Pane p1 = new Pane();
    Pane p2 = new Pane();

    Arc arc = new Arc(150,150,100,100,0,360);
    arc.setType(ArcType.CHORD);
    arc.setFill(null);
    arc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    arc.setStrokeWidth(20);

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100);
    rectangle.setX(100);
    rectangle.setY(100);

    Tooltip.install(arc, new Tooltip("Semiring"));
    Tooltip .install(rectangle,new Tooltip("Rectangle"));

    p1.getChildren().add(arc);
    p2.getChildren().add(rectangle);

    root.getChildren().addAll(p2,p1);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[Nothing happens on the rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqeUV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
p1.setPickOnBounds(false);
```

This essentially means mouse events are only delivered to `p1` if the mouse is over a non-transparent pixel in `p1`. Thus when the mouse is not over the arc, mouse handling is delegated to `p2`, as required.

Comment: Thank you, that was just what I need to do. It is worth noting that it matters which layer the p1.setPickOnBounds(false); is set on. It has to be the outer layer or it doesn't work.